# Flutter transparent black color

Tags: flutter, colors, transparent

How to make transparent black color in flutter like the background color  of icon’s in the picture below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the icon with a container and add color to it

```
InkWell(
onTap: (){},
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(7),
   child : Icon(Icons.mute),
  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5)
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
color:Colors.transparent,
```

if you use **Card  Widget** you need to make elevation zero

like this

```
elevation: 0,
color: Colors.transparent,
```

or if you want to reduce opacity of colors you can use

```
Colors.black.withOpcaity(.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DecoratedBox with the property backgroundBlendMode, and black color with opacity:

```
DecoratedBox(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
    backgroundBlendMode: BlendMode.darken
  )
  child: * your child *
);
```